# Tire and Elastic Search - Object Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, elasticsearch, tire

I'm having a little difficulty with the Tire and Elastic Search functionality.

I have a Listing that has a Property. I'm trying to get a basic search form working so that I can create a query from the Property.

```
# listings/index.html.erb

<%= form_tag searches_listings_path, method: :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= text_field_tag :property_postcode, params[:property_postcode] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

At the moment, whenever I try filtering down the search results, it seems like the property_postcode is being ignored and all results are being returned.

```
      # Listing.rb
include Tire::Model::Search
      include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
    indexes :id, type: 'integer'
    indexes :title, boost: 10
    indexes :description, analyzer: 'snowball'
    indexes :posted_at, type: 'date'
    indexes :property do
      indexes :postcode, :type => 'string'
    end
  end

  def self.search(params)

    tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 5, load: true) do
      query do
        boolean do
          must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
          must { term "property.postcode", params[:property_postcode] } if params[:property_postcode].present?
        end
      end
        end
      end

   def to_indexed_json
    to_json(:include => { 
              :property => {
                :only => [:postcode]
              }
            })
    end
```

And finally for the property

```
#Property.rb
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :listing, touch: true
  after_touch() { tire.update_index }
end
```

Then finally

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS=Listing FORCE=true
```

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

Comment: Also, if I don't put in a query and just the postcode in the URL http://localhost:3000/list/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&property_postcode=w1d2eb it doesn't raise to_curl exception that I put within the tire.search method

Comment: Can you turn on logging with `Tire.configure { logger STDERR }` and post a link to pastie/hastebin/gist/etc with the output? (With sensitive data filtered.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Property.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 5, load: true) do
    query { string params[:query], default_operator => "AND" } if params[:query].present?
    filter :term, "property.postcode" => params[:property_postcode]  if params[:property_postcode].present?
end
```

be sure to turn on routing in your mapping too

```
mapping :_routing => { :required => true, :path => property.postcode  } do
```